# Incluir contenido html/php desde otro fichero

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando en una web sencilla sin framework, y esta web debe tener un **header** y un **footer** en todas las páginas, son 3, la cosa es que no quiero estar copiando ese footer y ese header todo el rato en cada una de las páginas con lo cual me gustaría tenerlos hechos en un archivo a parte o en 2 archivos y incluirlos dentro de mis ficheros para que se visualicen.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: para html echale un ojo a estos enlaces [enlace 1](http://www.elwebmaster.com/general/html-%E2%80%9Cimport%E2%80%9D-importa-html-dentro-de-otro-html)  y [enlace 2](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para eso tienes la función include. Puedes programar una página header.php y otra como footer.php y llamarlas en las páginas que los necesites.

Para llamar a un fichero usando la función include bastaría con esta sentencia dentro de tu código php:

```
<?php

//Includes es el directorio donde estaría header.php. Puedes darle el nombre que quieras
include("includes/header.php");

?>
```

Luego en el header escribes tu código html. Con esto podrás reutilizar las páginas sin necesidad de estar escribiéndolas constantemente.

Referencias PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

Si solo son 3 copiar pegar el header y el footer tampoco es tanto. Pero si luego vas a ir ampliando esta bien tu idea de tener como una pagina maestra donde encuentres siempre tu cabecera y tu pie.
Te comento que tienes varias opciones:
1.- Puedes usar Adobe Muse te permite crear paginas maestras para crear la cabecera y pie de tu pagina.
2.- Puedes hacer esto con jquery: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712338/make-header-and-footer-files-to-be-included-in-multiple-html-pages)
3.- También lo puedes hacer con php: (Artículo completo aquí: http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head>
<title>Home page – My Website</title>
<meta http-equiv="description" content="page description" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">@import "styles.css";</style>
</head>

<body>

<?php include("includes/header.html");?>
<?php include("includes/navigation.html");?>

This is the content of the page

<?php include("includes/footer.html");?>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar a usar la funcion include de php.
http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

Si la aplicación sigue creciendo, los include también llegarán a ser un problema, por ejemplo, si el usuario quiere que el menú cambie de lugar, deberás ir a mover el include en todos los archivos que lo llamen. Yo creo que es mejor hacer un contenedor, como el índex.php, que tiene los headers, footers, menús y demás, y que el contenido principal sea el include. Hay muchas maneras de lograr esto, pero el concepto es ese.